# Multiply every element of RDD with corresponding element in a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

for example:

```
x = RandomRDDs.normalRDD(sc, size=3, seed=0)
```

x is like this: [-1.3, -2.4, -4.5]
I want to multiply every element of x with a *different* number in a list [1, 2, 3] and add them to produce y.
here y equals -1.3*1 + -2.4*2 + -4.5*3

but i can only do this:

```
y = x.map(lambda i: i*2).reduce(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

here y = -1.3*2 + -2.4*2 + -4.5*2

how can i replace 2 in **x.map(lambda i: i*2)** with a diffrent number every time?

the final effect is like what we often do in python:

```
x = [-1.3, -2.4, -4.5]
w = [1, 2, 3]
y = sum(x*w)
```

or

```
sum([x[i]*w[i] for i in range(len(x))])
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using `zipWithIndex` and `map`:

```
x = RandomRDDs.normalRDD(sc, size=3, seed=0)
w = sc.broadcast([1, 2, 3])

x.zipWithIndex().map(lambda v: v[0] * w.value[v[1]]).sum()
```

Or,

```
import operator
x.zipWithIndex().map(lambda v: v[0] * w.value[v[1]]).reduce(operator.add)
```

Comment: OK, sorry about the late acceptance, I made a minor revise to make it work on my machine:

Comment: @Yvonne Feel free to suggest an edit to the answer, or write a comment so I can update as needed.

Comment: environment:python version 3.6, spark 2.3.0,  `x.zipWithIndex().map(lambda pair: pair[0] * w.value[pair[1]]).reduce(lambda a, b: a+b)` .

Comment: It's so efficient of you! the `operator.add` works perfectly, but are you using pythoon2.X? In python 3.X, `lambda (k, i)` is not supported, and the element of  `x.zipWithIndex()` is a tuple like (-1.3, 0), I cannot unpack it anymore, so I have to use indices like what I do in the last comment: `x.zipWithIndex().map(lambda t: t[0] * w.value[t[1]]).reduce(operator.add)`.

Comment: @Yvonne you're right, I was using python2 with pyspark. Will update. Thanks!